# Get values from multidimensional object to list

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have object:

```
data = {
    "usa": {
        "a": {
            "min": 1,
            "max": 2,
            "avg": 1.5
        },
        "b": {
            "min": 3,
            "max": 5,
            "avg": 4
        }
    },
    "canada": {
        "c": {
            "min": 1,
            "max": 2,
            "avg": 1.5
        }
    }
}
```

I would like receive all max values from second dimension, for example:

```
function getMaxValues(country: string): number[] {
    const maxValues: number[] = data[country]???

    return maxValues;
}
```

I any better way than iterate over this object and collect results? In other languages are special functions for this. I don't want use iteration because this object is very large and usually specific functions for this are more efficient.

Comment: A function in another language like what? what function? You always have to iterate over an array to aggregate some information. I guess they're doing it just not in plain sight.

Comment: I‘m a bit confused. In the title, you‘re talking about an array, but all I see is an object.

Comment: @Felix functions like map.

Comment: @GabeRAMturn sorry, my mistake. I have updated the question.

Comment: @emervi `map` is basically just an iteration over your array returning a function for each item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `country` object `values` then `map` to get `max` value.

```js
let data = {
    "usa": {
        "a": {
            "min": 1,
            "max": 2,
            "avg": 1.5
        },
        "b": {
            "min": 3,
            "max": 5,
            "avg": 4
        }
    },
    "canada": {
        "c": {
            "min": 1,
            "max": 2,
            "avg": 1.5
        }
    }
}

function getMaxValues(country) {
    const maxValues = Object.values(data[country]).map(v => v.max);

    return maxValues;
}

console.log(getMaxValues('usa'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
Object.values(data).flatMap((country) => {
   return Object.values(country).map(({max}) => max);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the entries of the object:

```js
const data = {
    "usa": {
        "a": {
            "min": 1,
            "max": 2,
            "avg": 1.5
        },
        "b": {
            "min": 3,
            "max": 5,
            "avg": 4
        }
    },
    "canada": {
        "c": {
            "min": 1,
            "max": 2,
            "avg": 1.5
        }
    }
};

const maxValuesPerCountry = Object.entries(data)
  .reduce( (acc, [key, value]) => 
    ( {...acc, [key]: Object.entries(value).map(([, v]) => v.max) } ), {} );

console.log(maxValuesPerCountry);
console.log(`usa: ${maxValuesPerCountry.usa}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```